# Returning SELECT data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select, return

I have a SqlDataSource and a literal:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CategoryNameSQL" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Categories] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int16" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Literal ID="CategoryName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

What I'm trying to do is return the category name that has as certain ID, and then change the text for the literal with the retrieved name from the database. How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dvSql = (DataView)CategoryNameSQL.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRowView drvSql in dvSql)
    {
        CategoryName.Text = drvSql["Name"].ToString();
    }   
}

protected void CategoryNameSQL_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["Name"].Value = Request.QueryString["ID"];
}
```

Source: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/64/Bind-Data-From-a-SqlDataSource-to-a-Label

Comment: I tried it and I got these errors: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Select(System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments)' has some invalid arguments
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments'

Comment: I've corrected answer. You need to add event handler to `Selecting` event `Selecting="CategoryNameSQL_Selecting"`

Comment: It worked! Thanks. However, it seems like a lot for simply reading a database entry, doesn't it?